# Rails - create methods for checking user roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using this kind of checks in many parts of my application

```
if user_signed_in? && current_user.role.label == "admin"
      # do something
end
```

I decided to create a method in the `User` model (devise) that will contain this check

```
# app/models/user.rb
def is_admin?
    user_signed_in? && self.role.label == "admin"
end

def is_editor?
    user_signed_in? && self.role.label == "editor"
end

# etc etc
```

So I can use this instead, just for more usabillity.

```
if current_user.is_admin?
   # do something
end
```

However I get an error for undefined user_signed_in? method. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`signed_in` is not a method available within the model, only within the controller.  Neither is `current_user`

You're better off making a method in the ApplicationController.  Make it a helper method so you can also use it in views...

```
  class ApplicationController
    helper_method :admin?
    def admin?
      current_user && current_user.role.label == "admin"
    end
  end
```

You can then use it and you don't need to attach it to a user object.

```
<% if admin? %>
<%= "this is an admin" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3):

`user_signed_in?` will be a controller method added by devise I'd imagine

I would either add it in a helper or have it as a method in your application controller

```
class ApplicationController
  def is_admin?
    user_signed_in? && current_user.role.label == "admin"
  end
  helper_method :is_admin?

  def is_editor?
    user_signed_in? && current_user.role.label == "editor"
  end
  helper_method :is_editor?
end
```

`helper_method` will make it accessible to the view

Answer (score 2):

Try this, if want to define this method in user model, do like this

## in user model

```
  def is_admin?
    self.role.label == "admin"
  end
```

And use it any where in your view like this

```
<% if current_user && current_user.admin? %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach is is to use [rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify) gem. rolify allows you to create roles for your user and you just check `user.has_role`

Comment: I have followed this https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-a-default-role-to-a-User in order to add roles